# External script - Detect if user has an active admin session

Tags: magento-1.8, php, security

I would like to detect if the user has an active admin session via an external script. I have the below code but the security issue with this is that someone could simply copy the cookie from one PC to another and it will still evaluate. Can anyone suggest another way of doing this

```
include('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ob_implicit_flush (1);

$sesId = isset($_COOKIE['adminhtml']) ? $_COOKIE['adminhtml'] : false ;
$session = false;
if($sesId){
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_session')->read($sesId);
}
$loggedIn = false;

if($session)
{
    if(stristr($session,'Mage_Admin_Model_User'))
    {
        $loggedIn = true;
    }
}
var_dump($loggedIn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,you can achieve this by making a file in root of magento like test.php
and put this code

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));
if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  echo "welcome sweet boy";
}
else
{
  echo "You Are Cheater";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work but I have now updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check for admin sessions?

```
//get the admin session
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));

//verify if the user is logged in to the backend
if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
   //do stuff
}
else
{
  echo "go away bad boy";
}
```